How to hide or disable the cmd console when starting an executable
I wrote an executable that displays a window on the screen and gets some use input. It is bound to ⊞ Win+N:
#n:: Run "C:\Perso\dev-perso\dly\dly.exe"

My problem: this also opens a cmd (or PS) console which sometimes covers the actual program:

Is there a way to start an executable without the associated console?
I tried, per the documentation, to use the Hide or Min parameter, but this alters the behaviour of both programs, not only the console.

There are two types of Windows applications : Graphical or console.
If the executable is a console application, then it would automatically
display a CMD window as its output when started.
Windows needs to know before the program starts running which
subsystem it's going to use. Once the program has started running,
it's not possible to go back and request the other mode.
In programming, the difference is in the definition of the main procedure
of the program.
Your program is of the console subsystem, probably because it's much
simpler to program (doesn't need a message pump).
A console program can hide its own console by using the
GetConsoleWindow function
with the
ShowWindow function.
The specific code for implementing this is up to you, or you can ask
for details on
Stack Overflow
which is the place for programming questions.

Thank you for pointing me to the right direction! This is a Go program and adding -ldflags -H=windowsgui during the build fixed the issue. Thanks!

I am coding in Java; compile it executable by GraalVM native.
To hide console I have to do another step, after constructing executable.

lets say I compiled the project 'com.tugalsan.gvm.cloud' to a native executable as 'com.tugalsan.gvm.cloud.exe '.

First I am copying the executable as with a 'noconsole' tag with the cmd below:


copy com.tugalsan.gvm.cloud.exe com.tugalsan.gvm.cloud.noconsole.exe


Then I am running 'editbin.exe' as below.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64\editbin.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS com.tugalsan.gvm.cloud.noconsole.exe


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
